# How to maintain visibility of different linear layout of same xml on scrolling view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working with ViewPager.
I have made single XML for pager adapter (and I am having 4 pages pager) and in that XML only i am using multiple linear layout and set their Visibility to Gone. by default 1st linear layout's Visibility is on so that it can easily get set as a first page of pager now what I am trying is when I scroll the pager the first linear layouts Visibility should get gone and second linear layout's Visibility  should get ON(of same XML) and set to the pager and so on.

this is my xml (adapter)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sub_l3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/u_photos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Upload Photos \n (Ads with photos sell faster)"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_upload_1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_upload_2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_upload_3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_upload_4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sub_l1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ad_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Ad Title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_ad_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="Ad Title"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Category"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="Category"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sub_l2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Ad Description"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="Ad Description"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/sub_l4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Phone number"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_user_num"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="Phone number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Enter a city"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_user_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/form_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:hint="Enter a city"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_add_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_130sdp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_17sdp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this my `setOnPageChangeListener(..)` //here sub_l1,sub_l2,sub_l3,sub_l4 are the linear layouts//

```
form_pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            pages = position;
            if(pages==0){
                sub_l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else
            if (pages == 1) {
                sub_l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sub_l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else
            if (pages == 2) {
                sub_l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sub_l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sub_l3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else
            if(pages==3){
                sub_l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sub_l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sub_l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                sub_l4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Submit_add.page = position;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton3);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton4);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

I've wasted my 1 day in this please help 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
 {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    sub[position].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
Submit_add.page = position;
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        sub_l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sub_l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton);
        break;
    case 1:
        sub_l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sub_l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton2);
        break;
    case 2:
        sub_l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sub_l4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton3);
        break;
    case 3:
        sub_l2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        sub_l4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Submit_add.radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButton4);
        break;
    }
}
```

Explanation:
As i understand the problem is when scrolling back. For instance, if we scroll to the third page then the first and the second layout will be gone, and the third layout will be visible, and that's what we want. But if we scroll back to the 2nd page, then first layout will be gone, second layout will be visible but third layout will be visible too, because we never hide it. (4th layout is always gone because we never scrolled to the 4th page).

Comment: A brief explanation on why this approach works, as opposed to the OP's approach, would be helpful and would improve your answer.

Comment: Well, as i understand the problem is when scrolling back. For instance, if we scroll to the third page then the first and the second layout will be gone, and the third layout will be visible, and that's what we want. But if we scroll back to the 2nd page, then first layout will be gone, second layout will be visible but third layout will be visible too, because we never hide it. (4th layout is always gone because we never scrolled to the 4th page). Thanks for the tip @Christophe Strobbe :)

Comment: Pleased add that to your answer (use the 'edit' link just below it); comments are not permanent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not working. Only first layout is showing in all pages.

Comment: Sorry, you should move the same logic in onPageSelected method, and it will work. I will edit my answer.